# Length of Schengen tourist visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I understood the length of Schengen tourist visa is kind of standard to be 90 days. Now I am wondering, if in the itinerary I submit with my application I specify some period of time that lasts less than that time span, is it possible that they would issue the visa on a shorter length? or is it like, always when you get it, no matter what, it will be 90 days?

Thank you!

Comment: From personal experience, yes, they may give visas where the number of days you can stay is close to what you specify on your itinerary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Schengen C-Visa is a **short term** visa *up to* 90 days.

It is up to the discretion of the consulate to deside for how long the visa allows someone to remain 
(**Period of stay**)

- first time applicants could very well receive only the time given in their itinerary

In such cases the **period of validity** (i.e. when it can be used to enter and exit) will be 15 days more than the duration

- date of arrival + duration of stay + 15 days of "period of grace"

In this way, you can delay your arrival by a few days if needed.

---

> **period of validity**: the period during which the visa holder may use the issued visa:
>
> > **8.2 Period of validity**
> >     The period of validity should correspond to the information provided by the applicant. In all cases an additional "period of grace" of 15 days should be included in the period of validity to allow for a certain room for manoeuvre for the visa holder.
>
> **period of authorised stay**: the effective number of days that the visa holder may stay in the territory of the Member States during the period of validity of the visa. The period of authorised stay may be from 1 up to 90 days.
>
> > **8.3 Period of stay**
> >     The period of authorised stay should correspond to the intended purpose of stay or transit, while respecting the general rules in relation to the length of stay.

---

**Sources**:

- [Visa Code 2016-03-23 M4, 2018 C1](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:2009R0810:20160412:EN:PDF)

  - [Operational Instructions, 2019-05-14](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/20140709_visa_code_handbook_consolidated_en.pdf)

Comment: I would note that we have observed on this site that the "period of grace" is often omitted. This is contrary to the code.  Furthermore, visa officers often take the applicant's request for duration of stay at face value without checking it against the actual itinerary.  For example, an applicant might submit an application asking for a 9-day period of validity for an itinerary reflecting arrival on Friday 14 July and departure on Sunday 23 July.  Then they realize their visa is not adequate for the trip they have planned.